# How can I centralize modelstate validation in asp.net mvc using action filters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I write this code in several places and always repeat this logic:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyModel collection)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Json(false);//to read it from javascript, it's always equal
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            //logic here
            return Json(true);//or Json(false);
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(false);//to read it from javascript, it's always equal
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way using action filters, not to be repeating the `try-catch`, ask if the model is valid and `return Json(false)` as `ActionResult`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, you can create a validation `ActionFilter` or an `ExceptionFilter` to catch all errors, but why in the world are you doing a try...catch here? Throwing exceptions from something like validation is just wrong. What sort of errors are you expecting? Also returning `Json(true)` or `Json(false)` is wrong as well, that's what Http status codes are for.

Comment: I could answer, but everything you need is already typed out here: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/12/19/put-your-controllers-on-a-diet-posts-and-commands/ or you can watch a video of the techniques http://www.viddler.com/v/b568679c

Comment: yes, the if should outside the `try-catch`, besides that return a `Json (true)` is wrong, thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To conform with REST, you should return **http bad request 400** to indicate that **the request is malformed** (model is invalid) instead of returning `Json(false)`.

Try this attribute from [asp.net official site](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) for web api:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
     public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
     {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

A version for asp.net mvc could be like this:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
              if (!filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
              {
                   filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);  
              }
        }
}
```

Comment: checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69648844/129269 for the built-in solution

Comment: @riezebosch that is for .net core, this is for WebAPI and MVC

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, still valuable for people using core or 5.0+ finding this answer.

Comment: @riezebosch Sure, if you update your comment to reflect that, then I'll remove my comments (to remove some noise)

Answer (score 16):

If you want to do this in MVC6 or Mvc Core and without specifying your attribute on all of your Action methods then this is how you do it.

First create your ActionFilter

```
public class ModelStateValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext context )
    {
        if ( context.HttpContext.Request.Method == "POST" && !context.ModelState.IsValid )
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult( context.ModelState );
    }
}
```

Now create a convention in which you will apply this ActionFilter to all of your controllers.

```
    public class ModelStateValidatorConvension : IApplicationModelConvention
    {
        public void Apply( ApplicationModel application )
        {
            foreach ( var controllerModel in application.Controllers )
            {
                controllerModel.Filters.Add( new ModelStateValidationFilterAttribute() );
            }
        }
    }
```

And the last thing is to register this convention in MVC

```
    public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
    {
      services.Configure<MvcOptions>( x => x.Conventions.Add( new ModelStateValidatorConvension() ) );
    }
```

Comment: this is slightly more complete answer because it allows to avoid repeating even more code

Answer (score 5):

Starting from ASP.Net Core 2.1, the `[ApiController]` attribute will trigger automatic model validation:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
```

Consequently, the following code is unnecessary in action methods or custom `ActionFilterAttribute`:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#automatic-http-400-responses-1

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I only have one upvote to give away.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use the code from Khanh TO (from [asp.net official site](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api)):

To apply this filter to all Web API controllers, add an instance of the filter to the HttpConfiguration.Filters collection during configuration:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelAttribute());

        // ...
    }
}
```

Another option is to set the filter as an attribute on individual controllers or controller actions:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
  [ValidateModel]
  public HttpResponseMessage Post(Product product)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ValidateModelStateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {              
            context.Result = new ViewResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55465145/edit) some explanation to your answer