# When ModelState add validation error in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, modelstate

I am working on asp.net webapi project and i got a problem with `ModelState`.

I have a model Like this:

```
public class Model
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my code for processing the post request:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Model model)
{
    model.Date = model.Date ?? DateTime.Now;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

this code return bad request in response, why?

My question is when ModelState add validation errors and how to solve it?

Comment: First of all, I think you should centralize your ModelState validation using an ActionFilter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654669/how-can-i-centralize-modelstate-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-using-action-filters/21654903#21654903

Comment: ModelState validation is done `before` coming to your controller. That's why the code above fails. If you look at the link posted above, you see that we could intercept the validation in `OnActionExecuting` (which is executed before your Action Method)

Comment: How do you hit this action. please show that code.

Comment: ModelState validation is only done before hitting the controller if you use a global action filter which in this case he isn't. The key question is what request are you sending to the controller?

Comment: Also the fact that the DateTime is nullable and you have the required attribute is counter intuitive.

Comment: in your code, it does not make sense to use `[Required]` if you want to use your `DateTime.Now` as default value.

Comment: this is an example i want to know when validation occure.

Comment: What is the HTTP request you are sending to the action? There is nothing wrong with the code above. Please post the URL and the body of the request you are sending

Answer (score 0):

ModelState is gonne be invalid when you Date property is empty because of [Required] attribute. Even if the value changes with

```
    model.Date = model.Date ?? DateTime.Now;
```

ModelState is still be invalid.