# ASP.NET Core model binding and integers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Having this in my `Controller`

```
[HttpGet]
public string Get([FromQuery] QueryObject obj)
{
    return "value";
}

public class QueryObject
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

When I invoke the Get Method with this URL

http://localhost/MyController?**Number=HELLO**

I end up having a `QueryObject` instance with Number = 0

Why this ever happens? The query is clearly a BAD REQUEST, since `Number` is a integer and the query has a `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model binding will try to parse the request and bind to the properties of your object.  If it's invalid, then you'll find an error in the ModelState object.

e.g.

```
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // The ModelState is a Dictionary
            // holding details of the model binding errors
        }
```

For more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation

Comment: That's cool! Now I have another question. How can I automate it for every method? Can I integrate the check into the "pipeline" to throw a BadRequestException when the ModelState is not valid? Thank you!

Comment: You can deal with ModelState errors on every request using ActionFilters.  Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37093926/593751